# Lenovo Z400 low brightness video driver problem

Tags: 14.04, drivers, lenovo, brightness, gpu-driver

I have a laptop ideaPad z400 from lenovo that there is a brightness trouble. When it was with windows 10. I were with the same problem, but I could fix easily installing default driver. But now, I've installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS and initially it wasn't any problem but, when I tried to change the brightness, it keep very low.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and the same problem. Here is the solution I found:

1. Run:

   ```
   ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
   ```

   You should see:

   ```
   /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   ```
2. You need to adjust the first line (adjusting the second line won't do anything). Find the current brightness:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness
   ```
3. Find the maximum brightness:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/max_brightness
   ```
4. Adjust it to the desired value, say 15, by:

   ```
   echo 15 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness
   ```